# “Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null” on Ajax site

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, disqus

I am getting `Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null` error in Chrome. I use DISQUS comment script on the page.

The reason the error exist is because my `<div id='disqus_thread'></div>` is loaded in javascipt and injected into a div Foundation Modal in JavaScript when the user clicks an image.

I can't get this section out because it's built into the function that builds the HTML for the popup modal.

How can I solve this problem and prevent the error. I can't load the script when the modal window opened because it will inject the script several times.

Comment: Well you need to call the script when the modal is opened....

Comment: I don't know how to do that without having a duplicate injection of the script

Comment: So the modal does not have some sort if open event?

Comment: It does, when the user clicks the image, I have a function that builds the html for the modal in javascipt. In there I run the DISQUS.reset function to load the comment for that particular image. The problem is that DIQUS variable isn't initialized when I call that function. I was mistaken in the question, the disqus_thread div is being injected in javascript, not on the server.